# How to force Visual Studio compare to 'Latest Version' instead of 'Workspace Version'

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2022, tfvc, source-control-explorer

When I right-click a file in Source Control Explorer (which shows 'Latest' of 'No'), and choose 'Compare...', the dialog always defaults to Source Version: Type: 'Workspace Version'.  I *never* ever want to compare to the Workspace version. I *always* want to compare to latest version.

I change this bad default at least a dozen times per day. How can I force VS to default to "latest" instead of "Workspace"?
[image]

Comment: You probably can't. TFVC is a supported-but-deprecated feature; it's unlikely to ever receive any updates beyond security fixes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to fix this as far as I know, but you can call the diff from the commandline, so you can configure it as a "tool" in visual studio. [Using the commandline you can set your own desired commandline flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/folderdiff-command?view=azure-devops):

```
tf folderdiff [sourcePath] targetPath [/recursive] [/noprompt] [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]
[/filter:filter] [/filterLocalPathsOnly] [/login:username,[password]] 
[/view:same,different,sourceOnly,targetOnly]
```

[In Visual Studio you can configure "External Tools" to then invoke the commandline you want](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-external-tools?view=vs-2022). If needed wrap the CLI call in a batch script that asks for the desired prompts.

Comment: Theoretically you can probably write a Visual Studio Extension to open the dialog yourself in Visual Studio using a bit of C# code. Or to use a small screen automation tool like AutoHotKey that may be able to do this too: https://www.autohotkey.com/